# Address and Passport number in one word

Tags: single-word-requests

Is it possible to name User's address data and passport details in one-word? I have come up to **User Details**, but I don't really like it

Answer (score 2):

**Personal Information**

> http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/personal-information.html
>
> "Recorded information about an identifiable individual that may include his or her (1) name, address, email address, phone number, (2) race, nationality, ethnicity, origin, color, religious or political beliefs or associations, (3) age, sex, sexual orientation, marital status, family status, (4) identifying number, code, symbol, (5) finger prints, blood type, inherited characteristics, (6) health care history including information on physical/mental disability, (7) educational, financial, criminal, employment history, (8) others' opinion about the individual, and (9) personal views except those about other individuals."

It doesn't specify passport/drivers license numbers, but they also are "personal information".

This information can also be referred to as "Personal Details".